# How to define iterator for a set whose compare function I have defined explicitly?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, set

Set I have defined:

```
set < Node*, bool (*)(Node *, Node *) > visited(Node::compare);
```

It's compare function definition:

```
struct Node {
    int config[8][8];
    static int n;
    Node *parent;
    static bool compare(Node *, Node *);
};    
int Node::n = 0;    

bool Node::compare(Node *a, Node *b) {
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            if( a->config[i][j] != b->config[i][j]) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Now, at some point of the code I want iterate through it. However following code isn't working.

```
for(set <Node*, bool (*)(Node*, Node*)>::iterator itt = visited.begin();      itt != visited.end(); itt++) {    
    delete (*it);    
}
```

Error is :

```
error: no match for 'operator<'
(operand types are
    'std::set<Node*, bool (*)(Node*, Node*)>::iterator {aka std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<Node*>}'
     and
    'std::set<Node*, bool (*)(Node*, Node*)>::iterator {aka std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<Node*>}'
)
```

Comment: Curiously, what happened to using `for(auto& iter : container)`?? - Not using C++11?

Comment: Typo: you added an extra `()`. You need `set <Node*, bool (*)(Node*, Node*)>::iterator`. But just use `auto`.

Comment: Apart from the typo @juanchopanza mentioned, the condition in your `for` loop isn't quite right. Use `itt != visited.end()` rather than `itt < visited.end()`

Comment: If you don't have a C++11 capable compiler and can't use type-deduction using `auto` or range-for, then consider using a type-alias (i.e. `typedef`) for the set. Easier to type all that "templaty" stuff only once, and then use a nice name for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a bunch of erroneous parentheses in your template declaration:

```
set<Node*, bool(*)(Node*, Node*)())>::iterator
                                ^^^
```

Remove those and the error will go away.

Aside from that, I would strongly recommend using `auto` instead:

```
for (auto it = visited.begin(); it != visited.end(); ++it) { ...
```

Or even better, if possible, use range-based for loops:

```
for (const auto& node : visited) { ...
```

Comment: Yes, I removed those extra paranthesis. It was formatting error.

Comment: However, using auto gives an error: 'it' does not name a type.